# when we should use angular service?

Tags: angular, angular-services

From what I understand, we use services in the case of inter and intra components communication where we hide multiple or complex data structures. Is it true we only use services in the case of persistent data structure? So what are cases we should not use services?

Comment: Do you have an actual programming issue? Or just a code structure question?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I am not sure which category it falls into, but it is related to understand the underlying structure and decisions we make to select one over the other. Like Array vs List. I don't know enough to tell the different, but I thought I was on the right track when I decide to go with service for data sharing between components, but is this correct?

Comment: yes its correct using @Injectable service you can share data between  components and also for call http service.

Comment: is this the right practice? I keep hearing about bad or good practice from what we should not use and what we can use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590418/5695162

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I Would beg to differ with the statement you made.

> From what I understand, we use services in the case of inter and intra
> components communication where we hide multiple or complex data
> structures.

Instead of answering *when we should not use angular service?* I would answer what, why and when to use services?

### Service

A Service is a class with a specific purpose, and In Angular, we use services  mainly for three purposes.

**1.To Implement any Business Logic that is independent of any Component**

.
**Example**
Assume you want to calculate the age from DOB, Now you provide the year
and The logic can give you age you would not need an HTML view to do that
,it is component Independent

**2. Access to Shared Data.**
When passing data between components that lack a direct connection, such as siblings, grandchildren, etc, you should use a shared service.
You could either use RXJS **[`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject)** or **[`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject)** for cross component communication.

*The advantage of using `BehaviorSubject` or a `Subject` for cross-component interaction over plain `getters` and `setters` is you don't need to manually trigger a method to fetch latest data. Whenever the data is changed all the components where service is injected are automatically notified.*

**[What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject???](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43348463/5695162)**
**3. External Interactions**
1.Accessing REST Web Services Using `Http`
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Why use Services in Angular**
Angular distinguishes components from services in order to increase modularity and reusability.
**[`and It's Good Practice to Delegate complex component logic to services`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#delegate-complex-component-logic-to-services)**

> From **Angular Style Guide**
>  Do limit logic in a component to only
> that required for the view. All other logic should be delegated to
> services.
>
> Do move reusable logic to services and keep components simple and
> focused on their intended purpose.
>
> Why? Logic may be reused by multiple components when placed within a
> service and exposed via a function.
>
> Why? Logic in a service can more easily be isolated in a unit test,
> while the calling logic in the component can be easily mocked.
>
> Why? Removes dependencies and hides implementation details from the
> component.
>
> Why? Keeps the component slim, trim, and focused.

*Usage of Services In Angular also ensures that you are not violating **[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)** and **[SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**  principles of software development.*

**[`Providing Services`](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services)**
**FROM Angular Docs**

> Should you provide a service with an `@Injectable` decorator, in an
> `@NgModule`, or within an `@Component`? The choices lead to differences in
> the final bundle size, service scope, and service lifetime.
>
> When you register providers in the `@Injectable` decorator of the
> service itself, optimization tools such as those used by the CLI's
> production builds can perform tree shaking, which removes services
> that aren't used by your app. Tree shaking results in smaller bundle
> sizes.
>
> Angular module providers `(@NgModule.providers)` are registered with the
> application's root injector. Angular can inject the corresponding
> services in any class it creates. Once created, a service instance
> lives for the life of the app and Angular injects this one service
> instance in every class that needs it.
>
> A component's providers `(@Component.providers)` are registered with
> each component instance's own injector.
>
> Angular can only inject the corresponding services in that component
> instance or one of its descendant component instances. Angular cannot
> inject the same service instance anywhere else.
>
> Note that a component-provided service may have a limited lifetime.
> Each new instance of the component gets its own instance of the
> service and, when the component instance is destroyed, so is that
> service instance

#### TLDR

if we want an instance of a dependency to be shared globally and share `state` across the application we configure it on the `NgModule`.
If we want a separate instance of a dependency to be shared across each instance of a component and it’s children we configure it on the components `providers` property.*

To get a Clear Picture Go through **[Angular's Hierarchical Dependency Injection system](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)**

Well, it's recommended to Always register application-wide services with the root AppModule which makes a service singleton(it will live as long as our application lives) but it entirely depends upon the use case.

If the sole purpose of the service is to share data between sibling components and to provide a couple of helper’s methods.***Register it with component providers and make it a non-singleton
service.***

*The benefit is that when Angular destroys the component, Angular will also destroy the service and release the memory that is occupied by it.**@[Credit](https://netbasal.com/angular-services-do-not-have-to-be-singletons-ffa879e62082)***

**[FAQ](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq)**

Comment: that was a bunch of Details.tanx

Comment: @Vikas Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Where did you hear that is bad practice?
Using service for getting data from API by HTTPRequest or sharing data between components is good practice, check my example here:
[Share methods between two components in same page Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559675/share-methods-between-two-components-in-same-page-angular/50559773?noredirect=1#comment88130120_50559773)

Important thing that you have to remember is that Services are an application-wide singleton. **Therfore put services only into CoreModule, and import CoreModule only once in AppModule, nowhere else.** You don't want each module to have its own separate instance. (More about the difference between CoreModule and SharedModule: [Angular2: CoreModule vs SharedModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695931/angular2-coremodule-vs-sharedmodule))

Yet there is a real danger of that happening if the SharedModule provides the Service. It might be required for example if you are using Service for some reusable component, eg. in directive which is actually in SharedModule. Then you have to use `forRoot()` whilst you importing ShareModule, example:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { MyDirective } from './my.directive';
import { SomeService } from './some.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    MyDirective
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ SomeService ]
    };
  }
}
```

Some other module:

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: No Angular Services do NOT have to be always Singletons it Depends on the use case. One of the disadvantages is You are not releasing memory when you register it with `ngModule's` providers array.

Comment: I discuss my plan with someone, and he suggested i shouldn’t use service because it should only be used with data that needs to sit there for a while. While what I need to do is only displaying data from the data. My argument is I have complex manipulation and multiple components, therefore it should be right to use it.

Comment: @vikas I see that since it declare in the up in the root and hold on to memory maybe that why I should only use when it is necessary