# Is it a good practice to use shared services to avoid duplicate API calls for fetched data?

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have a scenario where I fetch vehicle details from the backend in one component (ValuationComponent). Once the data is fetched, I need to use the same data in another component (OtherComponent) for various operations.

Instead of making a separate API call in OtherComponent, I'm considering using a shared service to store the fetched data from ValuationComponent and retrieve it in OtherComponent. This way, I can avoid duplicate API calls and ensure consistent data across components.

Is this approach considered a good practice? Are there any potential drawbacks or alternative solutions I should consider?

In my scenario, I have successfully fetched vehicle details from the backend in the ValuationComponent using an API call. The fetched data is stored in a local variable within the component.

In the Other Component, I want to access the same vehicle details without making an additional API call. To achieve this, I'm considering using a shared service that holds the fetched data. This way, I can simply retrieve the data from the shared service in Other Component.

Comment: That's one of the main purposes of services.  Sharing data across the application. The most obvious drawback I'm seeing in your case, is you not getting the most up to date vehicle information. You have to consider if in your case that will be a problem or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when we should use angular service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625913/when-we-should-use-angular-service)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631080/5695162

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIPyikqkFYE&ab_channel=AngularUniversity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely a valid scenario for using a service.

To take it one step further, rxJs / observables make it even easier without needing to cache it yourself with operators like [shareReply](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay)

> You generally want to use shareReplay when you have side-effects or taxing computations that you do not wish to be executed amongst multiple subscribers. It may also be valuable in situations where you know you will have late subscribers to a stream that need access to previously emitted values. This ability to replay values on subscription is what differentiates share and shareReplay.